# Calculating A from this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am having trouble with the following question

> > If A and B are positive integers and $A^2 + B^2 = 36$ Then what is $A$? The choices are 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10.

How does one show that answer is 10?

Comment: Surely by mistake. You seem to be having a run of mistakes in your sources.

Comment: Is it $36$ or $136$?

Comment: A^2 - B^2 =36 so A=10 , B=8  OR Marvis's comment

Comment: The answer to the problem as written is not $10$. The only possibility is $36=6^2+0^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible (integer) solutions are:
$$A = 0,\quad   B= ±6$$
or
$$A = ±6,\quad   B= 0.$$

If the question would have been $A^2+B^2 = 136$ on the other hand, then the solutions would be:
$$A = ±10,\quad   B = ±6$$
and
$$A = ±6,\quad   B = ±10.$$